# How to get icon from current system theme in bash script (ubuntu)?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, themes, ubuntu-14.04, gnome

In Ubuntu 14.10, I would like to display a notification with an icon from the current system theme.  In the following code, line 3 is an example of what I mean:

```
1  #!/bin/bash
2  # Display a notification with an icon
3  ICON="$(somehow-get-path-to-system-theme-root-dir)/rest/of/path/to/icon.svg"
4  notify-send -i $ICON "Some notification text"
```

Does such a command exist, and if so, what is it?

Comment: I'm looking for the answer to the same question. However, in your example, notify-send accepts an icon name and looks up the path itself, so you don't need to,

Answer (score 4):

I think you should do something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
# Display a notification with an icon
THEME=$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme | tr -d "'")
ICON="/usr/share/icons/${THEME}/rest/of/path/to/icon.svg"
notify-send -i $ICON "Some notification text"
```

Comment: This applies to Gnome only. For Cinnamon: `gsettings get org.cinnamon.desktop.interface icon-theme`